# Circles to represent datapoints in Graphite?

Tags: graphite

Can Graphite produce a graph like "Number of Users"  in the picture below ?
&lineMode=connected , should take care about connecting the circles.

**How to produce something like the circles to clearly indicate each value in the series ?**

[image: Graph I want to mimic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but [Grafana](http://grafana.org/) can do that (and can query from Graphite). See the logins example here (if the link works): http://play.grafana.org/#dashboard/temp/QCvU7BN_S1GbsNyLFUV2MA